# Laravel - Returns null when retrieving a property from object

Tags: php, laravel

Example: I make a query using User Models `$object = User::find($id);`

When I make return `$object`. Then it return `{"balance" => 1, "id" => 2}` But when I make return `$object->balance` . Then return empty I have try `gettype` and it return object.

Update: When I try `json_decode($object, true)['balance']`. It's work

What was wrong with this ? Why can't I access it from original `$object` ? Someone please help me resolve this issues. Thanks

Comment: post complete code and model relationship as well

Comment: Might be there is a method name "balance" in your `User` model which makes the relationship to the other model (i.e. Balance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$balance = $object->balance;` doesn't work for you then you may try the following:

```
$object = User::find($id);
$attributes = $object->getAttributes();
$balance = $attributes['balance'];
// or
$balance = $object->toArray()['balance'];
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It have work. But, can you explain for me why `$balance = $object->balance;` not working, please ?